# for-loop and indexed array doesnt work

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, indexed

I want to create a 2-dimensional array with an index-number in each first element.

(my previous question brought me to this point >)

this works:

```
$('#create_indexed_array').click(function() {
    var new_array = [[9,9],[9,9],[9,9],[9,9],[9,9]];
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        new_array[i][0] = i;
    }

    alert(JSON.stringify(new_array));

});
```

BUT this works not:

```
$('#create_indexed_array').click(function() {
    var new_array = new Array(new Array());
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        new_array[0][i] = ""; // create cols
    } 
    for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        new_array[i] = new_array[0]; // create rows
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        new_array[i][0] = i; // set index
    }
    alert(JSON.stringify(new_array));

});
```

**EDIT:**
my final working version (so far):

```
var myArray  = [];
var rows = 5;
var cols = 2;

for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    myArray [i] = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        if (j==0) myArray [i][j] = i;
        else myArray [i][j] = '';
    }
}

alert(JSON.stringify(myArray));
```

(r) mostly by jfriend ;)

still don't know why it isn't possible to declare the 2D array at the beginning with: myArray = [[]]

Comment: This code is working.... NOT! and the username is sasha... coincidence?

Comment: `var` is not needed for the second two i's. The declarations will get hoisted to the top of your function.

Comment: call me baron, jbabey  --- yes duplicate, but I edited the first (deleted original question), and then it seemed lost.. duno    --- yes, second var not needed, but thats not the problem is it?

Comment: @Bergi - where's the closure?

Comment: @jfriend00: There's the word "closure" in the title of that question, nothing else. Don't know what it refers to.

Comment: originally I thought I'll need another function to handle the 'i' in there.. fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your current pattern, it will work like this:

```
$('#create_indexed_array').click(function() {
    var myArray = [[]];
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        myArray[0][i] = ""; // create cols
    } 
    for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        // create copy of first row in each other row
        myArray[i] = myArray[0].slice(0); 
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        myArray[i][0] = i; // set index
    }
    alert(JSON.stringify(myArray));
});​
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/vJDPp/

One thing you have to remember is that assigning an array assigns a reference to that array, not a copy so if you want each element of the array to be different, you have to physically make a copy of the first row to put in the subsequent rows.  I'd also recommend changing the name of `new_array` because that sounds so much like a function name that it makes the code confusing to read to someone who doens't know it.

---

If you're just trying to initialize a 2D array to all 9's like in your first code example, then this would be much simpler:

```
$('#create_indexed_array').click(function() {
    var myArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        myArray[i] = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            myArray[i][j] = 9;
        }
    }
    alert(JSON.stringify(myArray));
});
```

Or a function version:

```
function create2DArray(lenX, lenY, initVal) {
    var myArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < lenX; i++) {
        myArray[i] = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < lenY; j++) {
            myArray[i][j] = initVal;
        }
    }
    return(myArray);
}
```

Comment: right, the reference was the problem. thanks a lot to all!

Comment: @sasha - I added a much simpler 2D array initialization example.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use it with an embedded for loop?

```
For(var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
     For(var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
          new_array[i][j] = i; //set index
     }
}
```

That way it sets the index all at once. You'd have to declare it first.

The problem before was that you were treating it like two separate arrays, an array of items, and an array of that array of items. A 2D array is 1 array of 2 dimensions.

Comment: I think you mean `for` instead of `For`

Comment: This doesn't generate the same result as the OP's second block of code is trying to do.

Comment: I'm not used to case sensitive languages anymore I guess, my bad.

And I guess I totally missed what the OP was trying to do?